# get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: django, django-views

I am learning how to use django, and I am trying to make some class based views. In this case I have a model named Recurso and I want to get an specific one based on it's id (the primary key).

This is my view:

```
class Recurso(View):
    model = Recurso
    def get(self, request, recurso_id):
        recurso = get_object_or_404(Recurso, pk=recurso_id)
        etiquetas = recurso.tags.all()
        context = { 'recurso': recurso, 'lista_etiquetas': etiquetas }
        return render(request, 'recurso.html', context)
```

And this is it's respective url:

```
path('proveedor/recurso/<int:recurso_id>', Recurso.as_view(), name='recurso'),
```

This is the Model:

```
class Recurso(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Etiqueta)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='SOME STRING')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + " de " + self.proveedor.nombre
```

This is the traceback I get:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evaho\Envs\stem4Girls\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\evaho\Envs\stem4Girls\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evaho\Envs\stem4Girls\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evaho\Envs\stem4Girls\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evaho\stem4Girls\appSTEM4GIRLS\views.py", line 32, in get
    recurso = get_object_or_404(Recurso, pk=recurso_id)
  File "C:\Users\evaho\Envs\stem4Girls\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 76, in get_object_or_404
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /proveedor/recurso/6
Exception Value: Recurso.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Comment: Can you please share the *full* traceback and your `Recurso` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By naming your view `Recurso` as well, it will use the *view* class, not the model class. You can fix this by renaming the view, for example to `RecursoView`:

```
class RecursoView(View):
    model = Recurso
    def get(self, request, recurso_id):
        recurso = get_object_or_404(Recurso, pk=recurso_id)
        etiquetas = recurso.tags.all()
        context = { 'recurso': recurso, 'lista_etiquetas': etiquetas }
        return render(request, 'recurso.html', context)
```

I would strongly advise to always use a `…View` suffix for your views to prevent clashes with models.

Comment: Thank you but now when I try to run the server it gives me this: path('proveedor/recurso/<int:recurso_id>', RecursoView.as_view(), name='recurso'),
NameError: name 'RecursoView' is not defined

Comment: @EvadelHoyoOrtizdeZárate: you probably should change the `import` statement in your `urls.py` to import the view, not the model.